# Shell script to check and insert IP addresses

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file containing a long list of IP addresses that are sorted. A sample of the file looks like this:

```
103.21.244.0/22     1;  #Cloudflare
103.22.200.0/22     1;  #Cloudflare
103.31.4.0/22       1;  #Cloudflare
104.16.0.0/12       1;  #Cloudflare
108.162.192.0/18    1;  #Cloudflare
141.101.64.0/18     1;  #Cloudflare
162.158.0.0/15      1;  #Cloudflare
173.245.48.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare
188.114.96.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare
190.93.240.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare
197.234.240.0/22    1;  #Cloudflare
198.41.128.0/17     1;  #Cloudflare
199.27.128.0/21     1;  #Cloudflare
```

I'm trying to write a shell script that does the following:

1. For a given IP address (e.g. `1.2.3.4`) or an IP range (e.g. `1.2.3.0/24`), find out whether it is already in the file.
2. If it is, do nothing. If it is not, then insert it into the file in the right place.

**Problems:**

A. I'm stuck at checking whether an IP address or IP range is already in the file because a simple grep won't do. For example, grep will return negative for the IP `188.114.98.200`, which in fact is already represented by `188.114.96.0/20`. Likewise for `188.114.98.0/24`.

B. I am also clueless about how to insert an IP address/range entry in the right place without messing the sorted order.

Can someone help? Thank you very much.

**Edit:**

Okay, after looking at the suggestions, I guess I don't have to needlessly limit myself to Bash, especially if there are already existing libraries in other languages that can get the job done easily.

Comment: As far as inserting into the right place, I would just append to the end, and then resort the file. not so sure about matching `..98.200` against `..96.0/20`. Good luck.

Comment: Please explain the logic by which you are determining how `188.114.98.200` is equal to `188.114.96.0/20` or `188.114.98.0/24`.

Comment: @AbhishekPathak presumably via some sort of netmask logic: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: The `CIDR` notation does present a small challenge. If all of your `CIDR` ranges in the text file are `>= 17`, you can `grep` for the first 3 components of the IP. If a match is found, you will then need to test the full-IP against the IP range. If `>= 8`, then check the first 2 components, and so on.

Comment: @AbhishekPathak I simply use `ipcalc` to check the results.

Comment: Hmm, in that case you can use ipcalc in your shell script to check against all the IP address. However, a much better approach might be to **standardise** all the IPs that go into your file. After that, it simply reduces to a search problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that comparing/matching IP-format strings will be quite annoying.

This [page](https://www.linux-magazine.com/w3/issue/64/Script_Tuning_in_Bash.pdf) (Listing 4) has a good and simple trick to convert an IP string into an array of integers, only using bash parameter substitution (documented [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), look for `${var#Pattern}, ${var##Pattern}`).

If you want to catch the mask, add something like `IP[5]=${tmp##*/}` (with the notations of the linux mag pdf).

For simple IP comparison, you can simply compare/match arrays of integers with bash's arithmetic evaluation `((...))` (documented [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Arithmetic_Evaluation) for instance).

For more complex CIDR matching, either you are willing to implement quite a bit of logic yourself, or try tools like `ipcalc` (check [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipcalc)) which is available on most Linux distros.

Comment: Thanks. But I may go with the suggestion from @klashxx if there is already a library to do the comparing and matching of IP addresses, even if it's not Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Not `bash`, but this *task* is quite simple using `Python`:

```
>>> print ips
103.21.244.0/22     1;  #Cloudflare
103.22.200.0/22     1;  #Cloudflare
103.31.4.0/22       1;  #Cloudflare
104.16.0.0/12       1;  #Cloudflare
108.162.192.0/18    1;  #Cloudflare
141.101.64.0/18     1;  #Cloudflare
162.158.0.0/15      1;  #Cloudflare
173.245.48.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare
188.114.96.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare
190.93.240.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare
197.234.240.0/22    1;  #Cloudflare
198.41.128.0/17     1;  #Cloudflare
199.27.128.0/21     1;  #Cloudflare

>>> import iptools
>>> [raw_range for raw_range in ips.splitlines()                     
... if '188.114.98.200' in iptools.IpRangeList(raw_range.split()[0])]
['188.114.96.0/20     1;  #Cloudflare']                              
>>>                                                                  
>>> [raw_range for raw_range in ips.splitlines()                     
... if '188.112.98.200' in iptools.IpRangeList(raw_range.split()[0])]
[]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with Python, but if it gets the job done, I'm open to it. After all, Python is already installed and it seems to be a hassle to create the logic to compare/match the IP addresses in Bash. Thanks for pointing me to the library iptools. Have to go find out more about it.